# how to monitor if a scheduled task in Coldfusion sets up correctly?

Tags: debugging, coldfusion, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to setup my first Coldfusion scheduled task and can't get it to work. I don't have access to the `cfadmin` so, I need to do it using the `cfschedule` tag. I'm setting up something like this:

```
<cfschedule action = "update"
    task = "taskManager" 
    operation = "HTTPRequest"
    url = "path/to/task_manager.cfm"
    startDate = "12/01/12"
    startTime = "10:30 PM"
    interval = "60"
    resolveURL = "Yes"
    publish = "No"
    path = "#variables.baseUrl#"
    requestTimeOut = "100">
```

Which I'm putting in `task_init.cfm`. If I open this page in the browser, no errors are reported, but nothing happens.

**Question:**
I know scheduled tasks need to be allowed in CFAdmin. Still is there a way to test if the task is running? The task should just send an email right now, so I can see if it is working, but I'm not getting anything, I'm curious as to whether I'm doing something wrong.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Ok, so I'm halfway there. I can list tasks like so:

```
 <cfdump output="dump.txt" label="catch" var="#createobject("java","coldfusion.server.ServiceFactory").getCronService().listall()#">
```

which gives me all currently scheduled tasks.

I'm calling my task like this now:

```
<cfschedule  
proxyport="80"
port="80"
action="update"
operation="HTTPRequest"
task="taskManager_init"
interval="60"
publish="NO"
requestTimeOut="500"
resolveurl="NO"
startDate="12/01/2012"
startTime="11:30:00 AM"
URL="http://www.page.com/t/task_manager.cfm"
>
```

which, when I call and then dump all tasks creates an entry like so:

```
 xx) [undefined array element]
```

instead of:

```
 xx) [struct]
disabled: NO
file: [empty string]
http_port: 80
http_proxy_port: 80
interval: xxxx
operation: HTTPRequest
password: xxxxxxxxxx
path: [empty string]
paused: NO
proxy_server: [empty string]
publish: NO
request_time_out: 500
resolveurl: NO
start_date: 12/12/2012
start_time: 1:00:00 AM
task: some task
url: xxxxx
username: xxxxxxx
```

I can remove my `[undefined array element]` calling:

```
 <cfschedule action = "delete" task = "taskManager_init">
```

So, I'm able to add/remove tasks, but they don't show up correctly in the list and hence don't execute as they should.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? (besides calling my sys-admin on Monday...)

Thanks!

Comment: Your start date is in an ambiguous format.  Maybe you and cf have different opinions as to what it represents.

Comment: hm. What would be a more generic format?  2012:12:01 00:09:00?

Comment: I've had good luck with the ansi/iso standard.  yyyy-mm-dd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look in the cfroot\lib\neo-cron.xml config file. That would confirm that the information has saved.

A running task can generate output or put details into a log file or DB. Even when the ColdFusion JVM is running perfectly normal, I have seen the scheduler run for months, and then just stop running.

Also `path = "#variables.baseUrl#"` looks strange. I don't think the task scheduler support variables as a part of the configuration options. You may have

Comment: I removed the path param altogether, because the task right now should only send a test mail to me, so there is no need to write anything to file.

Comment: That is a good test. It covers the scheduler and cfmail. ColdFusion automatically adds entries into the scheduler.log too

Comment: Yeah, it's more or less working now, except I'm not able to run setup the schedule. I'm getting no errors, when I run above snippet, so the `<cfschedule>` must execute normally. Still if I output all running tests, it's not there, so it's not firing... need to meddle some further. Thanks so far!